# Minimum transitive dominating subtournament

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

For any positive integer $k$, does there exist a tournament such that the smallest dominating set that forms a transitive subtournament has size exactly $k$?

A tournament that does *not* work for $k>2$ is one where the vertices are on a cycle and each vertex has an edge to $(n-1)/2$ following vertices clockwise -- in this case taking two opposite vertices already gives a dominating set which is also transitive, meaning $k=2$.

Comment: Do you mean "which" or "that" in the first sentence? That changes the meaning. Either way though, you should be able to construct it by starting with $k$ vertices and then adding vertices one-by-one such that each newly added vertex $v$ has only one in-neighbor, and that in-neighbor is among the $k$ vertices. After you do this enough many times, the smallest dominating set will be the set you started.